# How to set column width in Node js excel-export

Tags: node.js, excel

I am using nodejs excel-export for exporting xlsx reports . I want to set custom with for columns and as per documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-export I am setting width like

```
 {
            caption: key,
            captionStyleIndex: conf.captionStyleIndex || 0,
            type: me.getType(jsonArr[0][key], types[i]),
            beforeCellWrite: function (row, cellData, eOpt) {
               eOpt.cellType = me.getType(cellData, types[i]);
               eOpt.styleIndex = conf.styleIndex || null;
               return cellData;
            }
            width:key.length
  };
```

But it is not getting reflected in exported sheet . Am I missing anything ?